# What about $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Q})$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I've heard a lot about $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Q})$ (see for example Minhyong Kim's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/546/galois-groups-vs-fundamental-groups)), but $\mathbf{Q}$ is a field. So isn't $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Q})$ trivial? What's the point of studying it?

Comment: Well, it's not quite trivial. As a scheme it has a single point corresponding to the prime $(0)$, but a scheme is more than a set and a topology. It also comes with a ring of global functions, in this case $\mathbb{Q}$. 

Also, it is often useful in AG to consider maps to a "point". For rings lying over $\mathbb{Q}$, this is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @Isaac Why study $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Q})$ though?

Comment: Studying $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q$ is like studying $\Bbb Q$ using geometry; for example, the geometry $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q$ encodes information about field extensions of $\Bbb Q$ and things like $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q)$. So, in short, the geometry of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q$ is intimately related to (some might say the same as) number theory.

Comment: The "internal" properties you name are indeed not that exciting. However, "studying $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$" also means studying maps to/from $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$ from/to other schemes — external properties, so to speak. The data produced by these procedures is highly arithmetically interesting.